why GetPixel returns a little bit different values
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

int main()
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    HDC monitor = GetDC(NULL);
    POINT cursor;
    COLORREF color;

    while (TRUE) {
        if (!GetCursorPos(&cursor)) {
            puts("GetCursorPosError!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        color = GetPixel(monitor, cursor.x, cursor.y);

        if (GetRValue(color) == 75 && GetGValue(color) == 219 && GetBValue(color) == 106) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        printf("x: %ld y: %ld %d %d %d\n", cursor.x, cursor.y, GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));
    }

    ReleaseDC(NULL, monitor);

    return 0;
}

Why, even when my cursor is stopped, the program displays a little bit different color values, at the same coordinate, of course, while the picture also does not move, which is also of course. The values what I get should be like (75, 219, 106) but it is very close to this like (70, 226, 90).
I tried changing the screen resolution, but it didn't help.
And as you see I aslo tried to use SetProcessDPIAware() and that also didn't help!
Pls help me I want to know how to solve it!

Where did you get the value that you expect to see?

I must admit that I never looked into it from a programmer perspective, but slightly changed colors might be the result of some color profile that is applied for your screen. Did you use some colorimeter to create a profile for your screen?

@Gerhardh I get this value from https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime. This color is a trigger for a reaction on this site.

@Gerhardh I already thought about this, but I think I didn't set any settings that could lead to changing color values ​​at all points on the monitor all the time

@chux-ReinstateMonica .x is long
